# C++: condition variable

Tags: c++, condition-variable

What is the behavior of a condition variable that is signalled (`notify_all`) while it is not being currently waited on? Does the next `wait` return immediately or will the notification be silently dropped?

Comment: Perhaps [this `std::condition_variable` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) can help you?

Comment: "This makes it impossible for notify_one() to, for example, be delayed and unblock a thread that started waiting just after the call to notify_one() was made."

Comment: Short answer - notify_all only notifying all threads which currently waiting for the conditional variable. If no thread waiting, no any kernel level synchronization happening only a system call.

Comment: No waiters at the time of a cv notify means effectively nothing. It isn't like an auto-reset-event in Windows. You can't "set" it with state on the chance someone may eventually wait again, and you want that waiter to greedily return immediately. If this is a behavior you're looking for, you're almost assuredly using CV's *wrong*. Do not treat them as state. Rather, consider them a signal mechanism to notify *potential* waiters of change *predicate* data state, which is protected by the mutex you had better be using. It's the predicate data, not the cv, that should convey state.

Comment: Isn't that something that you can easily test in a short program?

Comment: @WhozCraig if you make this an answer, I can accept it

Comment: A condition variable is used to indicate that a condition has become true. So if it's already true, don't wait. The usual loop on a condition variable handles exactly that case: `while (!condition) cond_var.wait();`.